# running under a locked screen in android

Tags: android

I'm a Windows phone developer porting my apps to android.  I'm an android newbie...

Windows Phone has a "locked mode" where the user can lock the phone to get rid of problems like pocket dialing, and other accidental gestures. Locked mode is different from turning the phone off. Our WP7 apps can remain running in the foreground when the phone is in Locked Mode if we set the app up to do so.

In Android is there such a Locked Mode?  Do we have to do anything special to be able to keep running in the foreground when the phone is in locked mode?  Can we detect when we are running when in locked mode or not?
thanks, Gary

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to run in the foreground if your app isn't shown and can't be interacted with?

Comment: Don't confuse the generic term 'app' with an Android `Activity`. An `Activity` is just one type of Android application component and is designed as a UI framework primarily for user interaction. As such, when an `Activity` is no longer visible (when the phone auto-locks for example) it will be paused/stopped. You don't actually describe what you want your 'app' to be doing when the phone is locked - if you can explain further then somebody will be able to help you do it in an Android way.

Comment: CaseyB, Squonk: one of my apps is PhoneStalker http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/phonestalker/5afbc36d-2e10-4cac-a804-26ed90c661d4 Start it up, tell it to trace where the phone goes, lock the phone so you won't pocket dial.  WP7 doesn't have services yet (hope 8 does).

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have anything like that.  You will be notified when your app is no longer visible via the `onPause()` method and when it becomes visible again via the `onResume()` method. There is a lot more information about the `Activity` Lifecycle at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is off the phone is off.
If you want to continue processing when the screen goes off you can hold a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) which will keep the CPU on. 
Preferably this would be done in a service rather than a foreground activity

Comment: Or, if you don't feel like raping the battery completely, schedule a recurring alarm with the AlarmManager, aquire a WakeLock, get the location & let the device go back to sleep.

Comment: That's a good point. I was just assuming a constant use like audio playing or something.